# How to get notification that a System.Threading.Tasks.Task has completed

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0

I am currently replacing some home baked task functionality with a new implementation using the new System.Threading.Tasks functionality found in .net 4.

I have a slight issue though, and although I can think of some solutions I would like some advice on which is generally the best way to do it, and if I am missing a trick somewhere.

What I need is for an arbitrary process to be able to start a Task but then carry on and not wait for the Task to finish. Not a problem, but when I then need to do something with the result of a task i'm not quite sure the best way of doing it.

All the examples I have seen use either Wait() on the task until it completes or references the Result parameter on the task. Both of these will block the thread which started the Task, which I don't want.

Some solutions I have thought of:

1. Create a new thread and start the task on that, then use Wait() or .Result to block the new thread and sync the result back to the caller somehow, possibly with polling to the tasks IsCompleted parameter.
2. Have a 'Notify Completed' task which I can start after completion of the task I want to run which then raises a static event or something.
3. Pass a delegate into the input of the task and call that to notify that the task is finished.

I can think or pros and cons to all of them, but I especially don't like the idea of having to explicitly create a new thread to start the task on when the one of the aims of using the Task class in the first place is to abstract away from direct Thread usage.

Any thoughts about the best way? Am I missing something simple? Would a 'Completed' event be too much to ask for :)? (Sure there is a good reason why there isn't one!)

Comment: Out of curiosity, why not use BackgroundWorker?  It has the task completion, as well as cancellation notification.

Comment: `BackgroundWorker` is no longer needed now that `Task` is with us. BGW required a `SynchronizationContext`, which is optional with `Task` (enabling greater parallelism).

Answer (score 59, accepted):

I *suspect* you're looking for [`Task.ContinueWith`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270696.aspx) (or [`Task<T>.ContinueWith`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321274.aspx)). These basically say, "When you've finished this task, execute this action." However, there are various options you can specify to take more control over it.

MSDN goes into a lot more detail on this in ["How to: Chain Multiple Tasks With Continuations"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537612.aspx) and ["Continuation Tasks"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372288.aspx).

Comment: Yes I understand that, but it doesn't solve the problem of knowing when the sequence of Tasks has finished without calling Task.Wait() (and hence blocking) on the thread that started the task.

One approach I thought of (as above) was to use Task.ContinueWith to  chain a task which raises an event which interested parties can subscribe to. This will keep the original task atomic.

Comment: @bwilliams: Why not just expose the task, and interested parties can call `Task.ContinueWith`? I don't see in what way it *doesn't* solve the problem of knowing when the task has completed... it's a non-blocking call that says, "Call me back when this is finished."

Comment: (Or instead of exposing the task itself, you can provide your own method which then just calls `ContinueWith` internally. It's the same thing, really.)

Comment: Sorry, you are completely right. 

I originally read all the stuff on MSDN, including all the links you posted but for some reason I read Task.ContinueWith as taking another Task as a parameter for execution after the initial tasks completion, not a simple Action or Func. Thanks alot, although I feel stupid now :)

Comment: @Ben Williams: Don't worry - it can get pretty confusing :)

Answer (score 11):

```
 Task task = Task.Run ( () => { Thread.Sleep ( 2000 ); } );

 task.GetAwaiter ().OnCompleted ( () => 
   {
     MessageBox.Show ( "the task completed in the main thread", "");
   } );
```

Comment: I find this approach interesting since I just want to specify a callback, not a new task. However, ["this method is intended for compiler user rather than use directly in code"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task-1.getawaiter#remarks).

Comment: With this method await is waiting until this call completes also.

Answer (score 9):

In modern C#, one no longer needs to call `ContinueWith()` explicitly. An alternative to the original accepted answer would be to simply create an `async` method that `await`s the `Task` in question, and does whatever it wants when the `Task` completes.

For example, suppose you want to raise an event called `TaskCompleted` when the `Task` completes. You would write a method like:

```
async Task RaiseEventWhenTaskCompleted(Task task)
{
    await task;
    TaskCompleted?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

To "register" the wait, just call the above method. Add exception handling as desired, either in the method above, or in some code that will eventually observe the `Task` returned by the above method.

Comment: It is not always true! for example, this `await` will block the UI thread but the `ContinueWith` will be executed after first thread without blocking current UI

Answer (score 6):

You can apply a [task continuation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372288.aspx).

Alternatively, `Task` implements [IAsyncResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iasyncresult.aspx), so you can use the [standard approaches for that interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228975.aspx) (blocking, polling, or waiting on its `WaitHandle`).

Comment: For the task continuation topic please see my comment under Jon Skeet's post.

Blocking and polling I don't like the idea of as it will mean having to start another thread to keep the original thread that started the task responsive.

I did see I could use WaitHandle, but the documentation says the preferred way is to use Task.Wait(). That said, as that doesn't do what I want maybe the WaitHandle is the best for me

Answer (score 3):

I created a small example illustrating Jon Skeet's answer, which I'd like to share with you:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int cnt = 0; cnt < NumTasks; cnt++)
        {
            var task = new Task<int>(DoSomething); // any other type than int is possible
            task.ContinueWith(t => Console.WriteLine($"Waited for {t.Result} milliseconds."));
            task.Start(); // fire and forget
        }

        PlayMelodyWhileTasksAreRunning();       
    }
    static int NumTasks => Environment.ProcessorCount;

    static int DoSomething()
    {
        int milliSeconds = random.Next(4000) + 1000;
        Console.WriteLine($"Waiting for {milliSeconds} milliseconds...");
        Thread.Sleep(milliSeconds);

        return milliSeconds; // make available to caller as t.Result
    }
    static Random random = new Random();

    static void PlayMelodyWhileTasksAreRunning()
    {
        Console.Beep(587, 200); // D
        Console.Beep(622, 200); // D#
        Console.Beep(659, 200); // E
        Console.Beep(1047, 400); // C
        Console.Beep(659, 200); // E
        Console.Beep(1047, 400); // C
        Console.Beep(659, 200); // E
        Console.Beep(1047, 1200); // C
        Console.Beep(1047, 200); // C
        Console.Beep(1175, 200); // D
        Console.Beep(1245, 200); // D#
        Console.Beep(1319, 200); // E
        Console.Beep(1047, 200); // C
        Console.Beep(1175, 200); // D
        Console.Beep(1319, 400); // E
        Console.Beep(988, 200); // H
        Console.Beep(1175, 400); // D
        Console.Beep(1047, 1600); // C
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ContinueWith function with your routine as a first argument, and a task scheduler as the second argument given by TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext().

It goes like this:

```
var task1 = new Task(() => {do_something_in_a_remote_thread();} );

task1.ContinueWith(() =>  {do_something_in_the_ui_thread();},
TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```