# Show a message when the task is done in c#

Tags: c#

I have bunch of RAW images that needs to be converted to TIFF. I wanted to use parallel for each to take advantage of multiple cores in the cpu but I didn't want to freeze the UI so I created a task for parallel foreach.

I want to show a message pop up when the given task is completed. How do I do this?

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
      {
        Parallel.ForEach(files, (currentFile) =>
           {
              if (token.IsCancellationRequested) return;
              string filename = Path.GetFileName(currentFile);
              // Do stuff to convert raw to tiff
           });
         }, token);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get notification that a System.Threading.Tasks.Task has completed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462104/how-to-get-notification-that-a-system-threading-tasks-task-has-completed)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There really isn't a need to use the older `Task.Factory.StartNew` these days unless you have a specific use case to do so. Instead use the more modern `Task.Run`

Also, I assume you are using a new task so you don't block the UI. This is a good use case for the *async and await pattern*. You would do this by *awaiting* the `Task` returned from `Task.Run`, which in turn allows you to *offload* the work to the thread pool while creating a *continuation* on the calling *synchronization context* (UI thread).

At that point you can  safely show your message after the `Task.Run` is awaited.

```
// public async void OnSomeButtonClick(...)
public async Task DoSomething()  
{
   await Task.Run(() =>
   {
      Parallel.ForEach(files, (currentFile) =>
      {
          // ...
      });
   }, token);

   // safe to show a dialog or update the ui here
}
```

---

**Additional Resources**

- [Stephen Cleary - Async and Await](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html)
- [Stephen Cleary - StartNew is Dangerous](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html)

Comment: I'm gettting a CS0117: 'Task' does not contain a definition for 'Run' error for Task.Run

Comment: @MustafaBoyar oh dear, it seems like you are using *.net 4* or less, rendering this entire answer *null and void*. Is there any particular reason you are using such an old framework version ?

Comment: oh my god, how did I miss that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A more C# 8 oriented approach would be to use the ActionBlock class to manage the background processing outside of the UI thread.

This method uses "await foreach" which is an async implementation of a foreach loop introduced in c# 8

```
public static async Task AsyncParallelForEach<T>(this IAsyncEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, Task> body, int maxDegreeOfParallelism = DataflowBlockOptions.Unbounded)
{
    var options = new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
    {
        MaxDegreeOfParallelism = maxDegreeOfParallelism
    };

    var block = new ActionBlock<T>(body, options);

    await foreach (var item in source)
        block.Post(item);

    block.Complete();
    await block.Completion;
 }
```

You can call the method providing which task should be executed against each item of your collection. Once that method completes, you can show your message on the UI.