# Issues with Button not changing when using Process.Start() in Blazor

Tags: c#, process, blazor-server-side, process.start

I am having an issue where I want to change the button text while running a Process.Start().
Here's what I have:

```
<button class="btn-lg btn- @ButtonClass" disabled="@IsDisabled" @onclick="GenerateReports"><i class="@ButtonIcon"></i> @Button</button>

public partial class Index
    {
        private string Button { get; set; }
        private string ButtonClass { get; set; }
        private string ButtonIcon { get; set; }
        private bool IsDisabled { get; set; }

        protected override void OnInitialized()
        {
            Button = "Generate Reports";
            ButtonClass = "btn-primary";
            ButtonIcon = "fas fa-copy";
            IsDisabled = false;
        }

        private Task GenerateReports()
        {
            try
            {
                Button = "Please Wait. Reports Being Generated.";
                ButtonClass = "btn-secondary";
                ButtonIcon = "fas fa-spinner";
                IsDisabled = true;

                Process process = new Process();
                process.StartInfo.FileName = @"\\MyServer\E$\ObjectCode\Test.bat";
                process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
                process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = false;
                process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                process.Start();
                process.WaitForExit();

                Button = "Reports Generated!";
                ButtonClass = "btn-success";
                ButtonIcon = "fas fa-check";

                return Task.FromResult(true);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
```

Basically, what I am trying to do is change the button text while disabling it. If I comment the Process part out, it works fine. However, once I run the Process it does not change the button nor disable it.
Anything else I need to do in order for this work?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I always try to see if calling `StateHasChanged` helps. Try calling it right before you return.

Comment: @HansKilian, I tried that. It did not work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is caused by the fact the button is being disabled and the text is being changed, but the UI **is not updated** before GenerateReports() exits.

You can split this function into two separate functions, one that will be called in order to start the process (and store it in private value), the second one would be called after the process has been completed.

For the second part you can use the approach described here:
[How to get notification that a System.Threading.Tasks.Task has completed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462104/how-to-get-notification-that-a-system-threading-tasks-task-has-completed)

Comment: thanks for the answer. I did try to split and even use the StateHasChanged. However, that did not work either. As far as the process being completed, that's what the WaitForExit is for. It basically stops everything else until the job is complete. That part works fine since it does change the button to display the correct message.

Comment: JTO, following your way of thinking, I was actually playing with it and was able to figure this thing out. I ended up having to put a Task.Delay and then call the split function, like this:
  private async Task ChangeButtons()
        {
            Button = "Please Wait. Reports Being Generated.";
            ButtonClass = "btn-secondary";
            ButtonIcon = "fas fa-spinner";
            IsDisabled = true;
            StateHasChanged();
            await Task.Delay(3000);
            await GenerateReports();
        }

It worked like a charm.
Thank You!